# Evaluate: $\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\frac{\sin^4(nx)}{\sin^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Evaluate for any integer, $n$,

$$\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\frac{\sin^4(n\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x)}$$

Anyone able to provide a detailed prove of this? I can't seem to figure it out, I've tried using Euler's formula, but no luck.

Comment: I would not expect any nice expression for this. Do you perhaps mean that the limits of the integral should be $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$? Also, there is no statement to prove. Maybe you want us to prove that the integral (with the limits changed) is equal to $n\pi$?

Comment: is $n$ natural?

Comment: In any case, you could have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1505027/97236).

Comment: Sorry, forgot a $\pi$ term...

Comment: Think even function, odd function, integrate by parts, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I will just simplify the expression to something manageable for the case when $n$ is an even number, say $n=2(m+1)$. You could take a similar approach for the case when $n$ is odd.

Let $\alpha=2x$ and $\phi=x$ then we have (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Other_sums_of_trigonometric_functions)) \begin{align}
\cos(x)+\cos(3x)+...+\cos((2m+1)x)&=\cos(\phi+0\alpha)+\cos(\phi+1 \alpha)+..+\cos(\phi+m\alpha)\\
&=\frac{\sin\frac{(m+1)\alpha}{2}\cos(\phi+\frac{m\alpha}{2})}{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}\\
&=\frac{\sin[(m+1)x]\cos[(m+1)x]}{\sin x}\\
&=\frac{\sin[2(m+1)x]}{2\sin x}\\
\end{align}
Therefore 
$$\frac{\sin^4[2(m+1)x]}{\sin^2 x}=2^4\sin^2x\Big(\cos(x)+\cos(3x)+...+\cos((2m+1)x)\Big)^4.$$

Therefore $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{\sin^4[2(m+1)x]}{\sin^2 x}dx=2^4\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\sin^2x\Big(\cos(x)+\cos(3x)+...+\cos((2m+1)x)\Big)^4dx$$

The latter is tedious but doable for any value of $m$.